# How to select the 1st or last Element of a LIST column in Cassandra CQL?

Tags: list, cassandra, cql

I have a Cassandra table of files, similar to the following (fake) structure:

```
CREATE TABLE files{
filename: text;
versions:LIST<{timestamp, filesize}>
}
```

I carefully always insert the latest version at the beginning of the LIST.
And I tried to run

```
select filename, versions[0] from files;
```

I met the following error:

SyntaxException:

I couldn't find a solution on StackOverflow and Internet. Just wonder whether this is possible in Cassandra CQL? Of course, if there is no such a solution, I will process data at client side.

Thank you in advance,

Ying

Comment: There are official docs https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html

Answer (score 2):

The functionality is not yet available [CASSANDRA-7396](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7396).

As of now you will have to fetch the complete list and filter it at application level.